# Como puedo limpiar la cache de cliente en Angular2?

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Como puedo limpiar la cache de cliente en Angular2 (final version, no RCx)?

Cada vez que despliego algún cambio realizado en una app en el servidor no se refleja en la página a menos que limpie la cache del navegador. En Angularjs si conozco algunos métodos para "eliminar" la cache del navegador pero en Angular2, he probado distintas opciones como las que menciono a continuación pero sin éxito...

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-copyright',
  templateUrl: 'copyright.component.html' + myGlobals.fileVersion,
  //styleUrls: ['copyright.component.css'],
  providers:[VentanaModalComponent, EntitiesService]
})
```

myGlobals.fileVersion tiene como valor '?tmplv=' + Date.now();

pero no funciona. Mejor dicho, si carga el copyright.component.html?tmplv=xxxxx pero para que cargue otra version de ese html tengo que refrescar manualmente la pagina. (es decir, siempre carga la versión antigua)

También he probado la opción de limpiar la cache desde código con el RuntimeCompiler.clearCache(), pero nuevamente sin éxito....

Gracias de antemano a todos.

Comment: a nosotros s enos presento ese mismo problema y lo hemos resuelto haciendo copia de seguridad el sitio , eliminandolo y volviendolo a subir ...